# how do i assign a list of data from text file to array value, row and column number in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have the list below in a text file

```
0,0,apple
0,1,dog
0,2,chicken
1,0,elephant
1,1,cow
1,2,tiger
```

I would like my @arr to be

```
$arr[0][0] = apple
$arr[0][1] = dog
$arr[0][2] = chicken
$arr[1][0] = elephant
$arr[1][1] = cow
$arr[1][2] = tiger
```

first number to be row, second number to be column, third to be the array value

Comment: Have you tried splitting the values on `,` and assigning the values to an array?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the code, as you haven't demonstrated that you've made any effort to work out how to do this. But here are some clues.

- Open a file and link it with a filehandle using [`open()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open)
- Read data from a filehandle using [I/O operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators)
- Remove the newline from a record using [`chomp()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp)
- Split a record into fields using [`split()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split)
- Learn about two-dimensional arrays in [perldoc perllol](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol)